# Readonly a particular rows field value of sales order line for appropriate condition in odoo10

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-10

I want to make 'readonly' a single row of sale order line for particular condition. Can it is possible for a check box, if check box(is_pack) condition is true, than that row is readonly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make readonly a particular row for any condition.

Comment: can you please describe how?

Comment: When a apply  particular condition for a row for example : if check box condition is true than particular row filed is read only and i have done this recently.

Comment: So can you please read question first ? It is not about making field readonly it is about making perticular row read only.Now can you please describe how to achieve it ?

Comment: yes it's work for a particular row like i am done when select a product pack i than row is readonly but when select a product than is work normally.

Comment: please add the example, because if you says it is possible it dosen't mean that you have given answer. You have to give example how ?

Comment: I think you post foolish answer just for the increment of your karma , am i right ?

Comment: hey my task is work so i am reply this it's work other wise why i am put my nose in this matter.

Comment: still you have not given example ? if you says possible then you have to mention how ?

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible to make readonly specific row (sale order line), because it is an `one2many` field and `readonly` attribute will apply on the field level not on record level. so in my openion you have to extend `one2many` field widget.

Comment: I add boolean in 'product.template' for product_id. When this boolean is checked then my product work as product pack. And i try to make 'readonly' "quantity" field in sale order line when product_id select pack as product. But, i now found any solution regarding this. I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: @PAWANSHARMA: you have mention that you want to make readonly perticular row in above question.you have not mention about to perticular field.

Comment: Hii Heroic, Here i applied condition and it's work.
<xpath expr="//notebook/page/field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='product_id']"
                       position="replace">
                    <field name="product_id" domain="[('is_pack','!=',True),('is_weight','!=',True)]"
                           attrs="{'readonly':['|',('iss_pack','=',True),('iss_weight','=',True)]}"/>
                </xpath>

Comment: @PAWANSHARMA : so as per your answer it will just make field readonly not a perticular  row and your question is about row. you need to be clear when you ask something.

Comment: I also applied this condition for every column of that row(product_id, product_uom_qty, price_subtotal, unit_price and description).

Comment: @PAWANSHARMA : so it is just work around , not a proper solution right ?

Comment: Ok Heroic, I think my task completed that's why i am thinking that's work. If you suggest that's not a proper solution, than it's good for me in future.
Thanks.